# How to build a Prime Redundant Architecture for N node(s) Software in small scale

Tags: java-8, tcp, nfs, distributed-system, rhel8

I have been assigned to design software that shall triggerCatastrophicEvent() if X.X.X.X is not reachable.
**Constraints:**

1. It has to be deployed in 2 separate servers to achieve availability.
2. **At any moment of time, any one of the software instances should only** **triggerCatastrophicEvent()** **since it is a catastrophic event!**
   **OS: RHEL 8.2 Language: JAVA-8**
   I have been thinking about this for quite a while. But, I have some doubts regarding my system design.
   Please find my initial design plan:-

- Have **state.cfg** file in NFS common mounted area which shall state which of the software is PRIME at that moment.
- Default any one of the software(s) as Prime and another as redundant when the software(s) starts.
- Have an individual **status.file**(**NFS common area**) which shall be written by respective software regarding their Most Recent Health every K seconds.
- At any moment let one instance check if another software status. file is not written since the Last X seconds, declare another instance to be dead, and make oneself prime while making another redundant by modifying the **state.cf**g
- Both config and status.file are available to each since they are mounted in each server so either of the software can read or write rach others file as necessary.

**Doubts**:

- In case the **NFS** issue occurs due to network/storage/etc then, this design fails.
- Kindly note I gave up the idea of sharing heartbeat through **TCP** socket/ Message Queue between two software since it shall also be impacted by network loss.

I am aware that designing a distributed system is a huge lesson still I gave it a go, but it seems my idea is falling short.
**strong text**

I would be highly obliged if the community can provide me with some leads or any idea.

Comment: I recommend you read about CAP theorum. Then argue which type of system do you want CP AP or CA. Then revise design accordingly.

Comment: ok ! I got it !